How to write adapter for CORS?
Im using axum and sea-orm for my backend. i got an error with CORS.
I tried to use cors layer
I dont have any idea how to fix it. I googled it, but all the other codes work well.
i did minimal reproducible example
code:
use axum::Server;
use axum::{
    routing::{get},
    Router, 
};
use http::Method;
use migration::sea_orm::DatabaseConnection;
use migration::MigratorTrait;
use migration::{
    sea_orm::{Database},
    Migrator,
};
use tower_http::cors::{Any, CorsLayer};

use std::{net::SocketAddr, str::FromStr};

// use ;
#[tokio::main]
async fn start() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let server_url = ("127.0.0.1:8000").to_string();
    let connection = Database::connect("sqlite://data.db?mode=rwc")
        .await
        .expect("Database connection failed");
    Migrator::up(&connection, None).await.unwrap();

    let state = AppState { connection };
    let cors = CorsLayer::new()
        .allow_methods([Method::GET, Method::POST])
        .allow_origin(Any);
    let app: Router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(|| async { "Hello, World!" }))
        .layer(cors)
        .with_state(state);

    let addr = SocketAddr::from_str(&server_url).unwrap();
    Server::bind(&addr).serve(app.into_make_service()).await?;
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct AppState {
    pub(crate) connection: DatabaseConnection,
}

fn main() {
    start();
}

and error: the trait bound `Cors<Route<_>>: tower_service::Service<axum::http::Request<_>>` is not satisfied the trait `tower_service::Service<http::Request<ReqBody>>` is implemented for `Cors<S>
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.29.0", features = ["full"] }
axum = { version = "0.6.19", features = ["macros"] }
tower-http = { version = "0.5.2", features = ["fs", "cors"] }
anyhow = "1.0.71"
migration = { path = "./migration" }
sea-orm = "1.0.0"
http = "1.0.0"


Please provide the full error and a [mre] including dependencies and their versions.

i did, sorry for for the bad wording

(I used the default migration, without any changes)

Please include your dependencies and their versions. I'm pretty sure you are using incompatible crates.

I did it (just now)

Can you upgrade the axum to the latest version ("0.7.5") facing breaking changes? or do you insist on the version ("0.6.19")?

There are some important changes in the new versions of axum. I think i can change my code a bit for new features.

I update my code for axum 0.7.5 and it works well. No problem with cors lol. Thank u. If u want, u can post answer for question

The solution to this problem is to update axum to version 0.7.5
axum = { version = "0.7.5", features = ["macros"] }
